# any utility can convert drawing box chars between utf-8 and ascii?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

There are some old code in ASCII doc. For example

```
/* main process
  ┌─┐  ┌─┐  ┌─┐
  │A├─>│B├─>│C│
  └─┘  └─┘  └─┘
 */
```

I want to convert it from ascii to utf-8.
I've tried uni2ascii, but failed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be precise: the ASCII character set does not include those line-drawing characters.  Your file is using some other character set.  You need to figure out what character set (or “code page”) your file was written for.  Then you can use a utility like [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to convert it to UTF-8.

For example, if it was written for [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), you can convert it to UTF-8 like this:

```
iconv -f CP437 -t UTF8 < myfile.c > utf8-myfile.c
```